# Shubuhat about demolition Dhul-Khalasa by Jarir(RA) and Ahmas

Tags: hadith, history, sunnah, sahaba, doubts

Assalamu aleykum wa rahmatuLlahi wa barakatuh dear brothers. Help please with one hadith from Islamophobes: the Pre-lslamic Period of Ignorance there was a house called Dhu-l-Khalasa or Al-Ka`ba Al- Yamaniya or Al-Ka`ba Ash-Shamiya. The Prophet (ﷺ) said to me, "Won't you relieve me from Dhu-l- Khalasa?" So I set out with one-hundred-and-fifty riders, and we dismantled it and killed whoever was present there
Historical context and what mean "killed whoever was present there"?
Source https://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/381

Comment: This site is not meant as a peer support.

Answer (score 2):

First note that the hadith appears in Sahih al-Bukhari and therefore is considered as trustworthy by sunni scholars.

Secondly if you open Sahih al-Bukhari and read the next hadith in the same section https://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/382 you will realize that Jarir and his hundred or hundred fifty companions demolished that "Deity and its house of worship". The prophet choose Jarir actually because he was from the tribe of Khat'aam who was living in that place. The 3rd hadith https://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/383 in the same section also doesn't by any means say that he killed people without any opposition or unfounded, but that he demolished the place of worship of an Idol and called and invited them to Islam before fighting them. And so on ibn Hajar (see in http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=7852&idto=7857&bk_no=52&ID=2250) quoted that al-Hakim quoted a hadith saying that Jarir جرير بن عبد الله البجلي was ordered to demolish the Idol (Dhul Khalasa) and the house of worship and to invite his tribe to Islam and to give them 3 days before using the sword against them and demolishing the Idol they were worshiping. So he didn't kill anybody unless they refused to refrain from worshiping other than Allah and/or fought him and his companions.

Comment: JazakaLlahu hayran. But still there is a thing that confuses me, I would like you to clarify. From the book of idols(hisham kalibi):
The women of the Khath’am were, then, humiliated
By the men of the Abmas, and abased.”
What mean “humiliated and abased by the men of the Ahmas”? Does this mean that these women were raped?

Comment: @AbdulkadirMagomedov do you have a reference for that quote? Would you mind sharing it.

Comment: https://answering-islam.org/Books/Al-Kalbi/khalasah.htm#19  The banu-Umamah, each wielding his spear,
Were slaughtered at al-Wahyab[19], their abode;
They came to defend their shrine, only to find
Lions with brandished swords clamoring for blood.
The women of the Khath'am were, then, humiliated
By the men of the Abmas, and abased."

Comment: What this mean?

Answer (score -2):

I don't know about thus report authenticity but taking women as war booty is part of Islam. Prophet SAW had a slave girl called Maria the Copt. A man does as he wishes with his property, it is allowed with the companions the right hand. remember Islam does not have to live up to disbelievers idea of what is good rather islam is what dictates what is good and what is evil. If the profit did it or approve of it then we accept it as good , full stop.

Comment: I can't see clear line in this post: The link for the hadith is given and it is from sahih al-Bukhari you say you don't know the authenticity of this report. You say taking woman as war booty is part of Islam. Later you say the prophet had a slave girl Maria the Coptic. Maria the Coptic was not a war booty. See [answer].